# Error of "Cannot deserialize" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I am a new coder on Spring Boot.  I was working on my project and get an error about reading the data file. Normally my code is longer. However, I prepared a sample code for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(BookApplication.class, args); 
        String url="http://localhost:8080/books/list";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String resp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
        JsonParser springParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
        Map<String, Object> map = ((org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParser) springParser).parseMap(resp);
        String mapArray[] = new String[map.size()];
        System.out.println("Items found: " + mapArray.length);
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
            i++;
        }
    }
```

and my Json File which I wrote into the database:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Harry Potter",
  }
]
```

So I have an error of:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[{"name":"Harry Potter"}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: looks like your json has a list as first elemet but you are trying to parse it to `map`

Comment: hımm how to fix that? I mean how to convert?

Comment: Answer seems so obvious, I can't believe it has to be said, unless of course you didn't bother to look at the documentation: Since the root of the JSON is an array / list, call **`parseList()`** instead of `parseMap()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @deadshot pointed out, the response is not a Map of String, Object . Rather a list of maps.

And you can shorten your code by entirely removing the parsing logic (using JsonParser ) by using **ParameterizedTypeReference**  like this:

```
    String url="http://localhost:8080/books/list";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<List<Map<String,String>>> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null,
        new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Map<String,String>>>() {
    });
    List<Map<String,String>> body = response.getBody();
    Assert.assertEquals("Harry Potter",body.get(0).get("name"));
```

If however, you want to go in the JsonParser way,

```
    String url="http://localhost:8080/books/list";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String resp = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);


    JsonParser springParser = JsonParserFactory.getJsonParser();
    List<Object> list = ((org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParser) springParser).parseList(resp);

    System.out.println("Items found: " + list.size());

    for (Object book : list) {
      Map<String,String> bookMap = (Map<String,String>) book;
      bookMap.forEach((key,val) -> System.out.println(key + " = " + val));
    }
```

Comment: hımmm actually my data is so long, I have 500 books and their authors inside my Json Data. How to convert your code to my code?

Comment: @Alkyonemis It doesnt matter , how much big data u have.

Comment: If you want to do it your way, i have added that approach too.. Please check

Comment: Thank you so much Abhinaba, the second one, what I was looking for.